# Я считаю нужным добавить в чужой вопрос одно слово, улучающее вероятность нахождения вопроса поисковиком, как лучше это сделать?

Tags: поддержка, правки

В этом вопросе
[Оставить только целые от десятичной дроби](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/577280/%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8-float-arduino/577285?noredirect=1#comment763959_577285)
я считаю очень желательно, чтобы было слово "округление" для улучшения вероятности нахождения вопроса поисковиком. Одно слово правкой нельзя добавить, тэга такого нет. Как лучше сделать?

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с [вариантами](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3392/176217).

Comment: Округление вниз десятичной дроби (оставить только целые)

Comment: А метки вообще убрать из заголовка. Основная добавляется автоматически.

Comment: Так что, будете редактировать заголовок-то?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, так вы же отредактировали. А про округление я не правильно понял, хотя отсечение дробной части это частный случай округления...